# What's the staleness interval good for?

Tags: iphone, core-data

When an managed object is fetched, and the staleness interval is set to 5 minutes, what happens after 10 minutes, when I access an property of that object?

Would Core Data then perform a fresh fetch request? Does that make sense? I can't think of a situation where data is already cached but the object is a fault. When can this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Core Data Programming Guide: Using Managed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html)

> Note that an object's staleness
>   interval is the time that has to pass
>   until the store re-fetches the
>   snapshot. This therefore only affects
>   firing faults—moreover it is only
>   relevant for SQLite stores (the other
>   stores never re-fetch because the
>   entire data set is kept in memory).

It only affects full fledged objects -- it does not affect those that are faults (ie "ghost objects" with no populated attributes.)

You really only need to fiddle with this in a complex setup where you have multiple context all changing the store simultaneously. On iOS apps, this is rarely necessary.

Comment: They are. However, "firing a fault" means to populate the objects attributes. If faults are "ghost" then "firing a fault" and "faulting" both mean "to materialize" or "to make concrete." The terminology evolved over several decades and is rather confusing. A lot of writers get it backwards which just makes it worse.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that faults and ghosts are the same thing, so dontWatchMyProfile's reaction might seem strange now.

Answer (score 2):

If the object in question is not a fault, but a fully realized object (it's properties have been populated), then nothing will happen if you access a property of this object in 10 minutes.

`stalenessInterval` affects only objects that are faults. If you have such an object and you initiate fulfilling a fault by, for example, accessing a property, then Core Data can either get property values from its internal cache or from a persistent store. If time in `stalenessInterval` since last fetch from the store has elapsed, then property values will be fetched from the store, otherwise–from the cache, which is much faster.

Yes, there can be a situation when the data is already cached, and the object is a fault. You can do this yourself by trimming the object graph for breaking relationship strong reference cycles.

> When you have relationships between managed objects, each object maintains a strong reference to the object or objects to which it is related. This can cause strong reference cycles. To ensure that reference cycles are broken, when you're finished with an object you can use the managed object context method refreshObject:mergeChanges: to turn it into a fault.